# Would this type of question have a place?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'd like to talk about a subject concerning all **multiplayer *(PC)* games** but it's not a regular question, is more of a thought I'd like to share and ask for **opinion** of others.  I'm pretty sure the correct answer would be the one I'd **subjectively** choose as it'd be **opinion and experience** based.

### Let's put it a bit to the ground and explain my *question*:

I'd like to ask for players' thoughts on how, lately, multiplayer games such as LoL are killing the communication experience between teams (*global chat is desactivated by default*) and in general (banning *bad* words).
From this kind of question, an answer like *"You have to do this, this and that"*, will not come so I was wondering how to deal with it.

1. Is this a valid question for **Arqade**?
2. Maybe this type of questions have a place in **Meta**?
3. In case **1** and **2** are a "**No**", how could it be formated so it becomes valid while preserving the main question?

Comment: Don't put it on meta. Meta is only for discussion about the site itself. You seem to want an open discussion, which won't work on main. Sometimes, despite our best intentions, things don't always have a form that works on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this type of question is the parts that you've bolded. Thus, I don't think this question would be a good fit for the main site at all. This is more akin to a forum discussion rather than a Q&A format.

One of the reasons to close a question is being primarily opinion-based. From the close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

As for whether it should be on the meta, @Ash has explained it well in the comment on your question. The meta is for posts about the site itself, not for "meta discussions" about gaming that don't belong on the main site.

Comment: Right, kind of knew that an **opinion based answer** would be the main problem for it to have a place here..

Comment: I've seen some off topic *(a bit)* questions in the past in the **Meta** side so yeah.. had some hope *(a bit)*